# will two weak acids lower their degree of dissociation when put together in solution compared to when put separately

Tags: ionic-compounds

When two weak acids are put in aqueous solutions separately they will have some value of degree of dissociation,  now when both are put together will there be a decrease in their dissociations, I think they should lower each other dissociation due to common ion effect (H+ from both) , the problem is that in my textbook they give resultant H+ion concentration by adding individual concentration , those values being same as if when put in separately .. can anyone please explain me what's correct mathematically ?

Comment: You are correct. Obviously the acid with the smaller pKa would contribute more to the H+ concentration than the other acid, but the other acid would contribute some too.

Comment: Thanks , atleast I know that I was correct , but how to calculate the new degrees of dissociation ? when we take suppose a weak acid with a strong one , I can calculate degree of dissociation by assuming that conc. of h+from strong acid part I constant (strong acid ) but I cannot do it here , because both are depreciating each others dissociation